# How to capture the values in a gridview dynamically in asp.net DevExpress MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

as I can make this code dynamically

```
public ActionResult EditingUpdate() 
{
 //...
 string fName = GridViewExtension.GetEditValue<string>("FirstName");
 string lName = GridViewExtension.GetEditValue<string>("LastName");
//...
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read the help pages, which are linked at the top of each Stackoverflow page, on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, it depends on how you want to present the action to the user. I would recommend you follow the example on the [DevExpress Demo Page](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/EditModes). They show you how to pass the model into your controller.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditingUpdate(MyObject model) 
{
    string fName = model.FirstName; 
    ....
    ....
{
```

Now, the following step is where you have few choices. You can call the controller method in several different ways, all from the gridview partial view. Again, refer to the [DevExpress Demo Page](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/EditModes). If you want to call the method from an edit action (which is what I assume based on your method name), then you use:

```
settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "EditingUpdate" };
```

But there are other ways of calling this method, such as

```
settings.CustomActionRouteValues = new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "EditingUpdate" };
```

It all depends when you want the gridview to call this method.

Follow the example in the demo, that will help you decide how you want it. Good luck!